# how to plot an exponential function's curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the code below, but when I run it, it shows me a linear plot instead of an exponential function curve.

I would appreciate your help if someone can tell me where I am wrong.
I expect an exponential curve when I do plotting instead of a linear graph.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

######### Constants
El      =   -0.70                   # resting membrane potential [V]
thresh  =   3                      # spiking threshold [V]


# VOLTAGE
T       =   100       # total simulation length [s]
dt      =   0.2       # step size [s]
time    =   np.arange(0, T+dt, dt) # time has 501 elements
V       =   np.zeros(len(time))         # array for saving Voltage history
V[0]    =   El
I = np.zeros(len(time))
I[100] = 1
counter=0
t_ref=5
tau=1.25
Weight=5

######### Simulation
def eps(s):
    return (s/tau)*np.exp(1-(s/tau))



for t in range(len(time)):

    spike_trains_window= I[:counter+1] #read I till counter says
    temp=0
    for i in range(len(spike_trains_window)):
        if spike_trains_window[i]==1: 
            s= t-i
            temp+=eps(s) #use an exponential function for computing temp
    V[t]= Weight*temp


    if V[t]> thresh:
        V[t-1]=3.5
        V[t] = El
        I= np.delete(I, np.s_[0:counter+t_ref], axis=0) #removing previous firing times+ incoming spikes in refractory period
        counter = 0
    else:
        counter+=1    


######### Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
line = plt.plot(V)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do not completely understand what your code is supposed to do, I see the following issue:

You have only on value in in `I` which is non-zero, so this part will be `TRUE` only 
once:

```
if spike_trains_window[i]==1:
  s = t-i
  temp+=eps(s)
```

This will assign a non-zero value to `V[t]` and `V[t-1]`. Because the value is bigger than `tresh`, we have `V[t]=EL=-0.7` and `V[t-1]=3.5`, this is exactly what I get in the plot.

So I think your code is working, there is no error, but probably it is not doing what you want it to do because you don't make it do what you want it to do

Comment: Thanks @Chelmy88 for your response...I am calculating V(voltages) based on an exponential function that i defined it in eps(s)...so when i compute V[t] with help of temp Variable....i expect an exponential function's curve...but it gives me a linear plot not curve...

Comment: But you only have non 0 V values for two points, how do you want it to be exponential curve?

Comment: OKay u can assume   I[100:300] = 1 instead of    I[100] = 1   but still it shows a linear plot not curve....now u have 200 non-zeros values

Comment: The issue is that your V[t] values almost always exceed the threshold. If you try with `I[1:100] = 1` you see some oscillation at the beginning due the the threshold value, followed by an exponential increase and an exponential decrease

Comment: If problem is threshold , even when i increase value of threshold to a big random number , still i get a linear function not a curve